# Creating a distribution histogram of a field in Elasticsearch index using Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, visualization, kibana

I have an Index consisting of a date and a `totalValue` field which only has values for a specific date. There are tens of thousands of rows (documents) with the same date value and different `totalValue`s. My goal is to create a distribution graph of those values. I have tried choosing `totalValue` as the horizontal axis, but then the vertical axis shows aggregate functions like count, sum, and median, which I don't want. Also I feel it should be able to automatically figure out the range of the field and do the proper binning based on that. Any pointers please?